# uses a function that calls another in a foreach loop dopar

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, golem

I have two functions myfunct1 and myfunct2. myfunct1 uses the myfunct2 function
I want to use these two functions in a foreach()%dopar%{} loop but i get a error:

*Error in {:
task 1 failed - "unable to find function 'myfunct2'"*

**utils_u1.R**

```
myfunct1 <- function(){return(myfunct2())}
myfunct2 <- function(){return(matrix(c("1", "2"), nrow = 1))}
```

**fct_f1.R**

```
#' @import doParallel parallel foreach
rbinddf <- function(){
  num_cores <- detectCores(); cl <- makeCluster(num_cores); registerDoParallel(cl)
  df <- foreach(i = 1:5, .combine = 'rbind', .export = c("myfunct1", "myfunct2")) %dopar% { return(myfunct1()) }
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(df)
}
```

**app_server.R**

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  print(rbinddf())
}
```

Comment: Solutions here: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/issues/1130#issuecomment-1960920273